# Pass parameters without using QueryString

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, bootstrap-table

I have an MVC application. On one page I have a partial view that displays a bootstrap-table. I have some javascript code that is triggered when a table row is double clicked. This code retrieves some values from the double clicked row and constructs a url then navigates to that url.

This works fine but the way I have created the url means that I have data visible as querystrings in the url. How can I achieve navigating without using querystrings. Oh and I need the navigation to a new window/tab if possible.

My javascript code for the double click is:

```
$mTable.on('dbl-click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {

        var cod = $('#hdCOD').val();
        var mv = mGetSelectedRow().CMonth;
        var yv = mGetSelectedRow().CYear;

        var diff_cv = moment.utc(cod).diff(moment.utc(yv + '-' + pad(mv, 2) + '-' + '24'), 'months', true);
        var plcf = '';

        switch(true) {
            case (diff_cv >= 2):
                plcf = 'past';
                break;
            case (diff_cv >= 1 && diff_cv < 2):
                plcf = 'last';              
                break;
            case (diff_cv >= 0 && diff_cv < 1):
                plcf = 'current';
                break;
            case (diff_cv < 0):
                plcf = 'future';
        }

        var url = 'ClaimMonth/ViewMonth?pn=' + mGetSelectedRow().Cpid + '&cm=' + mv + '&cy=' + yv + '&mt=' + plcf + '&cod=' + cod;
        window.open(url, '_blank');
    })
```

The partial view is called using razor syntax:

```
Html.RenderAction("GetSummaryForAdmin", New With {Key .pn = Model.PersonelNo})
```

I can't seem to find an equivalent function in javaScript that mimics the `New With {Key .pn = Model.PersonelNo}` I'm also unsure if this is the way to do this. I've thought about ajax call but I don't think I can make this open as a new window/tab.

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've found the following ajax.post method that gives me the document I want... In Developer Tools (F12 in Chrome/IE) using the network tab I can see the call for the document and if I preview it, it displays the data. But the page is not displayed in the browser.

Opening in a new window/tab is not a requirement but would be nice to have.

My new code replaces...

```
        //var url = 'ClaimMonth/ViewMonth?pn=' + mGetSelectedRow().Cpid + '&cm=' + mv + '&cy=' + yv + '&mt=' + plcf + '&cod=' + cod;
        //window.open(url, '_blank');
```

with...

```
        $.ajax({
            type : "post",
            url : "ClaimMonth/ViewMonth",            
            data :  {pn: mGetSelectedRow().Cpid, cm: mv, cy: yv, mt: plcf, cod: cod },            
            success : function(response) {
                window.open();
            },
            error : function(xhr) {
                console.log("error"+xhr.status);
            },
            complete : function() {
            }
        });
```

and I changed my controller function to accept parameters instead of reading request.querystring

Comment: if you want navigation with parameters, then pretty much you have to use the querystring. The only other way to move between pages and transmit data is using form submission with a POST. And then I'm not sure you can make the result open in a separate tab. But of course even then a curious user can easily see what parameters are being passed in a POST by watching the network (via the browser tools, or any other appropriate software). Why do you want to hide this data? It looks like all the values you are trying to hide are available on the page somewhere anyway

Comment: @ADyson correct.. the values are not sensitive... but customer prefers nice clean URLs. I've come across some code using Post which works but does not display the results. See my update

Comment: `window.open();` is just opening a blank window with no content. Interesting observation re your customer, I've never come across any users/customers who even noticed what was in their URL bar (in some cases they don't notice to the extent of not being aware if they are on the test system or the live one), never mind caring whether it looks neat or not.

Comment: But realistically most websites don't have neat URLs, especially things that involve searches, or commerce sites with links to products. Even google doesn't: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=test+search&oq=test+search&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i57j69i60l2j69i65l2.1448j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 . TBH I think you're making your code (and your life!) complicated for no reason. Just tell the customer that's how the web works, so they just have to live with it. If the software works, they'll soon forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use a combination of postback and [Session](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.session(v=vs.118).aspx).

- AJAX Post (as you have already) to send values back to the server.
- In the MVC action method which handles that postback, save the values to Session:

  ```
  Public Function ViewMonth(...) As JsonResult
      Session("SavedMonth") = New MonthObj(pn, cm, cy, mt, cod)

      Return Json(True)
  End Function
  ```
- When the AJAX Post returns successfully, open a new window with a different URL:

  ```
   success : function(response) {
          window.open('/ClaimMonth/AfterSave');
      },
  ```
- The MVC action method for that URL loads the saved data from session, then displays it.

  ```
  Public Function AfterSave() As ViewResult
      Dim model As MonthObj = TryCast(Session("SavedMonth"), ModelObj)

      Return View(model)
  End Function
  ```

Comment: Thanks buffjape... This works. I don't think there is a way for this to open in a new window/tab is there? I'll mark as answer at end of day if no-one has any suggestion on improving this solution so that is opens the page in a new window/tab.